# How can I properly create redirects from an array in Gatsby

Tags: node.js, wordpress, gatsby

I am working with Gatsby and WordPress. I am trying to redirect some URLs using the Gatsby redirect API. I write the query to get an Object and then I use the Map method to create an array of the items we need from that object. I then run a for Each method to get the individual data from that array but it fails on running the development server.

What is the Right way to do this?

```
const { createRedirect } = actions;
  
  const yoastRedirects = graphql(`
  {
    wp {
      seo {
        redirects {
          format
          origin
          target
          type
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `)
  const redirectOriginUrls = yoastRedirects.wp.seo.redirects.map(redirect=>(redirect.origin))
  const redirectTargetUrls = yoastRedirects.wp.seo.redirects.map(redirect=>(
    redirect.target
  ))
  
  redirectOriginUrls.forEach(redirectOriginUrl=>(
    redirectTargetUrls.forEach(redirectTargetUrl=>(
      createRedirect({
        fromPath: `/${redirectOriginUrl}`, 
        toPath: `/${redirectTargetUrl}`, 
        isPermanent: true
      })
    ))
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`createRedirect`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#createRedirect) API needs to recieve a structure like:

```
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createRedirect } = actions
  createRedirect({ fromPath: '/old-url', toPath: '/new-url', isPermanent: true })
  createRedirect({ fromPath: '/url', toPath: '/zn-CH/url', Language: 'zn' })
  createRedirect({ fromPath: '/not_so-pretty_url', toPath: '/pretty/url', statusCode: 200 })

  // Create pages
}
```

In your case, you are not entering to the correct fetched data. Assuming that the loops are properly done, you must do:

```
 let redirectOriginUrls=[];
 let redirectTargetUrls=[];

  yoastRedirects.data.wp.seo.redirects.map(redirect=>{
    return redirectOriginUrls.push(redirect.origin)
  });

  yoastRedirects.data.wp.seo.redirects.map(redirect=>{
    return redirectTargetUrls.push(redirect.target)
  })
```

Instead of:

```
  const redirectOriginUrls = yoastRedirects.wp.seo.redirects.map(redirect=>(redirect.origin))
  const redirectTargetUrls = yoastRedirects.wp.seo.redirects.map(redirect=>(
    redirect.target
  ))
```

Notice the `.data` addition in the nested object.

In addition, keep in mind that the `createRedirect` API will only work only when having a hosting infrastructure behind, like AWS or Netlify, both have plugins integration with Gatsby. This will generate meta redirect HTML files for redirecting on any static file host.

Comment: I used the redirects API inside the modules.export pages. The rest of the code is for creating the pages. That's why I didn't copy them. I added the .data to the queries but it still fails.

Comment: Can you debug if your data is being retrieved properly? The `console.log` you place there will be prompted in the terminal. Maybe the loops are the problem. I've assumed that they worked maybe not.

Comment: The problem is from those loops. The data is correct. I have viewed it in the console and everything is there.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Set the new arrays at the beginning and push the new values. Place a console log inside the `forEach` loop and change it to `map` loop if doesn't work. I don't know how it works that API internally.

Comment: I would try this now. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this now and it didn't work. I feel the problem is from creating the redirects inside a loop. Does it make any sense to create the loop in the from paths and topaths.

Comment: As you can see here https://levelup.gitconnected.com/programmatic-redirects-in-gatsby-7009a855e973 it's doable, maybe it helps you